# 3D Model Problems

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

When I add a model to my content and run the program I get the following error

> Invalid texture. face 0 is sized 522X360 , but textures using DXT
>   compressed formats must be multiples of four

Can anyone can help me? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out this [Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2b23b35-9723-4062-95b0-6cdcc0ecb793/xna-3d-models-invalid-texture) and [Solution](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/49783/302021.aspx). You need to make sure your texture size is a multiple of 4

Answer (score 1):

The answer is exactly what it says: the dimensions of your texture image aren't multiples of four (should ideally be powers of two) - just resize your texture images.

Set the width and height both to 512 for best results. (Use an image editor like GIMP instead of MSPaint to get a clean scale that doesn't look weird)